# Geometry Nodes: How can I target each spline individually in a curve object?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, instances, splines

Let’s say I want to build ladders with geometry nodes, using a bezier spline as « main » object.

- I would duplicate the spline to have two rails
- and add points on the curve to instanciate the ladder’s steps.

[image]

The first (index=0) and last point (index=point count-1) would be ignored for the steps instances, as those are the extremities of the ladder.

This works great.

But what if I have several splines in my curve object; because I want to have several ladders generated ?
This does not work anymore; as I can’t target the first and last point of each spline.

I’m searching a way to have Geometry Nodes considering each spline individually, and have the whole logic based on each spline.

Is this possible ?

Comment: why don't you just instantiate your "ready" ladders on e.g. geometry on points node? maybe a sketch would help what you want to achieve... ;)

Comment: ...I was just thinking of the exact same thing @Chris brought up.

Comment: @Chris : edited with a picture...

Answer (score 4):

i have no idea what you wanna make, but hopefully this helps:

i made ladders from beziercurves, and i put ladders on points of beziercurves:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a safety inspector: this is a nightmare; but visually it's pretty cool  – a ballet of ladders.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: Thank you very much, i appreciate that!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady & Chris, And I'm not a ladder expert, but I like your recent friendly interaction with each other ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Endpoint Selection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/endpoint_selection.html) node.

[image]

Using default parameters will remove the first and last point of each sub-spline.

Comment: This seems great ! I managed to remove points on a curve.  But this doesn't work to remove points after a "curve to points" node.

Comment: I guess you can transfer the information as an attribute by index or proximity from the curve to the points ?